# $\mathbb Z$ as an example of scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intuition, schemes

The idea behind Grothendieck's concept of schemes is that given a ring $R$ we can see $R$ as the ring of regular function over a topological space $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$. But I have difficulties to grasp this idea due to its abstraction. For example take $R=\mathbb Z$ the ring of integers -  that will be the ring of of regular function over a topological space which is $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Z)=\{p\mathbb Z : p \text{ is a prime number}\}$
so how is it possible to see $\mathbb Z$ as ring of function?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Don't forget $0\Bbb Z$. That's also in the spectrum.

Comment: @Arthur yes thanks

Comment: Dear tallola,  $R$ will be the ring of global sections of the structure sheaf of the scheme associated to $R$. The topological space is $Spec(R)$ with a certain topology, and the sections over a principal open set are some rings of fractions.

Comment: @orangeskid please can you less genius in your answer because i m self studing here and i want an answer that let me build some intuition not a kind of abrakadbra.

Comment: @orangeskid structure sheaf of the scheme i taught the scheme is a topological space with a sheaf

Comment: I recommend starting with $Spec\mathbb{C}[t]$. It's probably the most intuitive example.

Comment: @Кряжев Арсений since $\mathbb C$ is algebraically close the $spec(\mathbb C[t])=<t-a>$ so the ring of regular function over $spec(\mathbb C[t])$ will be what?

Comment: You have yourself mentioned that functions over $SpecA$ is $A$. Polynomials $f \in C[t]$ are thus functions, and their values in points $(v-a)$ are $f$ mod$(v-a) = f(a),$ so you get your function values in the usual sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of an element $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ as a 'function' $\phi_n$ on $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z} $ as follows:

For every $p\mathbb{Z} \in \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z} $, consider $\phi_n(p\mathbb{Z} )=\bar{n}\in \mathbb{Z} /p\mathbb{Z} =\kappa(p)$.

Here $\kappa(p)$ denoted the 'residue field' of the point $p$.

Comment: Gambit so $n:spect(\mathbb Z) \rightarrow \mathbb Z \quad (p\mathbb Z) \rightarrow  [n] mod p$

Comment: It is not an integer valued function in the 'traditional' sense. You should think of $n$ as 'function' which assigns to each prime ideal $p\mathbb{Z}$, a value in a field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Gambit so in cas $R=\mathbb C$ then for $a \in \mathbb C$ $a(<t-\omega>)=\bar \omega \in \mathbb C[t]/<t-a>$ is this right?

Comment: @tallola You mean $R=\mathbb{C}[t]$. Then $p(t)\in R$, will define a function: which assigns $(t-a)$ to $p(a)\in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: sorry it is indeed $R=\mathbb C[t]$ thanks a lot.